# Convert JSON format String into array in HIVE

Tags: json, oracle, hadoop, hive

I have a database column that stores JSON format strings.  The string itself contains multuple elements like an array.  Each element contains multiple key-value pairs.  Some value may also contain multiple key-value pairs as well, for example, the "address" attribute below.

```
[{"name":"abc", 
  "address":{"street":"str1", "city":"c1"},
  "phone":"1234567"
 },
 {"name":"def", 
  "address":{"street":"str2", "city":"c1"},
  "phone":"7145895"
 }
]
```

My ultimate goal is to get the single value of each field within the JSON string.  I will probably use explode() to do that but the explode() needs to have arrays passed into it, not a string.  So my first goal is to convert the JSON string into an array.  Can someone please let me know how to do it ?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this:

```
select concat(‘{“name”’,data_json) from your_table q1 --re-construct your json
lateral view explode(split(json_data,’{“name”’)) json_splits as data_json --split json at each {"name" tag into array and then explode
```

Note: I code is not tested as I don't have access to hive currently. This should definitely give you a good start OR you can always go with Hive SerDe for JSON `com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ruben123, go with Hive SerDe for JSON especially when your json is complex. There are several JSONSerDe available, eg. `com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe`, `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` [link](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

Make sure json is properly formatted, one line json for one record. So, your json should be:

```
{"name":"abc", "address":{"street":"str1", "city":"c1"}, "phone":"1234567"}
{"name":"def", "address":{"street":"str2", "city":"c1"}, "phone":"7145895"}
```

Create hive table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_json (
   name STRING,
   address STRUCT<
     street: STRING,
     city: STRING>,
   phone INT )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/your/hdfs/directory';
```

To select access field, simply

```
select name, address.street, address.city, phone from sample_json;

abc   str1  c1  1234567
def   str2  c1  7145895
```

Note: if JSONSerDe is not installed yet, you must run `ADD JAR`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: @jlp had posted that only one of his columns has json strings.  Since SerDe is essentially a serialization deserialization framework, JsonSerDe can be applied only on the whole table right? What if the user has a mix of data Json and non-json pipe delimitied? Even if the user uses a RegexSerde, the Json part will still be a string. In that case, how should we go about exploding the string json?